# Concurrent transactions in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

I have an accounts table.Balance of account id 1 is 550.Say one connection of mysql is doing this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update accounts set balance = balance - 200 where id = 1 #TIME t 
update accounts set balance = balance + 200 where id = 2 #TIME t + 100  
COMMIT
```

Now suppose another connection is doing this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update accounts set balance = balance - 100 where id = 1 and balance > 500 #TIME t  + 50 
COMMIT
```

I want to know what would be the final state of database and why?

Comment: It all depends on type of transaction isolation level.

Comment: @Mnemonics : Thanks!
I found this video very interesting.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHKHzwolbKU&list=PL584AsfOKiT7chf2ZpjjUvI0wu7afwlzQ